# Working with excel sheet in java

Tags: java, excel, prompt

I am second year student. i have to complete my java project but am facing some issues if anyone of you could help. My project is to enter marks of student in excel worksheet using java and calculating average of marks. i have written the following code but it is not working well ...

Here is my code ...

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.*; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class exceluser {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String St_Id = "";
        String Name = "";
        int Marks = 0;
        boolean keepRunning = true;


        //Blank workbook
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        //Blank sheet
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Seating Details");

        //create heading

        Row rowHeading = sheet.createRow(0);
        rowHeading.createCell(0).setCellValue("Student ID");
        rowHeading.createCell(1).setCellValue("Student(s) Name");
        rowHeading.createCell(2).setCellValue("Marks");

        //Font size and style loop for my headers


        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            CellStyle stylerowHeading = workbook.createCellStyle();
            Font font = workbook.createFont();
            font.setBold(true);
            font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
            font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
            stylerowHeading.setFont(font);
            rowHeading.getCell(i).setCellStyle(stylerowHeading);
        }
        int rownum=1;

        while(keepRunning){
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter student ID : ");
            St_Id = scnr.nextLine();
            if(St_Id.equals("EXIT"))
            {
                System.out.print("You have ended the program");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the student name : ");
                Name = scnr.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the marks of the student :  ");
                Marks = scnr.nextInt();

                //This data needs to be written (Object[])
                Map <String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
                data.put("2", new Object[] {St_Id, Name, Marks});

                //Iterate over data and write to sheet
                Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();

                for(String Key : keyset)
                {
                    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                    Object [] objArr = data.get(Key);
                    int cellnum = 0;
                    for(Object obj : objArr)
                    {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                        if(obj instanceof String)
                        {
                            cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                        }
                        else if(obj instanceof Integer)

                            cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
                    }
                }
                if(!(St_Id.equals("EXIT")))
                {
                    rownum++;
                }

                //Auto size my columns that will be filled out with user input info.            
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
                }
            }
            try{

                //save to excel file
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Student Grading Report.xls"));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Record added Succesfully...");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } 

    }//pub static void end brace    
}//pub class end brace
```

help me out in this code if anyone can.. this code when executes it left a row in excel after entering one student data and m facing issues in finding average of students marks..???

Comment: Proper indentation of your code will help you see what is happening at each point in your code

Answer (score 1):

This is an assignment so I'm not going to give you the code but will give you some points to consider.

- You really should use separate methods for different tasks - this will make your code easier to follow and also easier to write and debug.
- You currently can only enter one mark for a student at a time. You might want to put your Map outside of the loop and have the key as the Students ID and use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of Integers for you students marks. Even better would be to create a `Student` class to hold this data.
- To calculate the average you just need to calculate the average of values in the list for that student
- Don't use `System.exit(0)` to quit the program, rather use it to set your `keepRunning` boolean to false to break from the loop.
- Consider putting the code to write the data to the file outside of the loop after changing the above.